# How to use ddev commands in its own exec-host hooks for an automated backup

Tags: ddev

I've made a custom command to my ddev, creating a database backup with a single command (yes, I'm lazy, sorry).

I was thinking if there's some way to hook a ddev command, e.g. ddev poweroff to run another command or command sequence together.

The idea is to make a backup of all databases in a specific directory when I run the ddev poweroff.

Anyone have a clue about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `pre-stop` `exec-host` hooks can invoke ddev directly. Here's an example of a pre-stop hook that does both a snapshot and a traditional db dump:

```yaml
hooks:
  pre-stop:
    - exec-host: ddev snapshot --name=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
    - exec-host: mkdir -p .tarballs && ddev export-db --file=.tarballs/db.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).sql.gz
```

For more info on hooks, see [DDEV hook docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/configuration/hooks/).

Hope that helps!